# How to use an sum() function without group by?

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, having

I just have to omit those records whose sum of sales in all 53 weeks is 0 and would need the output without group by

Comment: Simply `select sum(col) from table where ...`

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data?

Comment: Can you share your table's structure, some sample data, and the the result you're trying to get? It's a bit hard to follow the question as it's currently phrased.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Postgres, Sql Server, MySQL, Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

You cannnot really get that in one query.
To get all years without any sum of sales, you have to sum the sales.

That is: 
Firstly:
`select YEAR(date) from YourTable group by YEAR(date) having sum(sales) > 0`

Then:
`select * from YourTable where Year in (<firstquery>) as aliasname
order by <anydatecolumn>`

If you are using mssql you can do that in one query using the OVER clause and partitioning